# Is it possible to crossfade songs on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, music

Is it possible to crossfade songs on an iPhone that are played through the iPod app?

If there is no native way to do this, are there any apps that can do this?

Comment: Intriguing question both from technical and usefulness aspects

Answer (score 6):

I'm sorry, I don't think it is possible (yet). If you had an old iPod Nano/Classic then I might have suggested 'Rockbox' (give it a google). [Send Apple a feature request](http://apple.com/feedback/ipodtouch.html) about it, they never know, if enough people bombard them with requests then maybe it will become a native feature.

Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: I didn't know ipod have different apps from iphone, except from obvious hardware differences. isn't it the same OS?

Comment: The iPod Classic (and the former Nano's) run a smaller iPod OS that is very closed and will not allow apps etc, and it is unlikely they ever will with the way iOS is developing and branching. However 'RockBox' (http://www.rockbox.org/) is an open source installer that replaces the base of the iPod's audio playing ability - the firmware. Replacing firmware is different to installing apps, its fiddling with something deeper than the final UI, installing something to the core. Sadly this will not work on iOS devices. Cheers, hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I added a new app myself, because I wasn't happy with the other ones out there.  MediaMix didn't allow scrubbing, and MyDJ applied a flat "n seconds" crossfade to all songs.  I wanted something more customizable, so I wrote Muxic.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/muxic-intelligent-crossfading/id547091143?mt=8

Comment: +1 Not sure why this was downvoted; it appears to be on-topic. There's nothing inherently wrong with suggesting your own app, if it's appropriate to a software recommendation question.

Comment: Dan, I appreciate the backup.  Yes, I wrote it, but if someone else had written it instead, I'd still post it.  I just wanted something nicer than the existing apps out there, so I decided to roll my own.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't the native iPod player, but [Media Mix](http://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/media-mix-free/id400416949?mt=8) (link to free version) allows crossfading.

Comment: +1 That's a pretty good app. The only drawbacks I see are that it doesn't play music in the background, and you can't scrub through songs.

Answer (score 1):

I use [My DJ](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/my-dj-with-crossfade/id334818456?mt=8) from the App Store, it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

[Stop&Go Music Player](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stop-go-music-player/id921581604?mt=8) is perfectly suited for people looking for a very simple way of crossfading songs on the iPhone.

Full disclaimer : I made it !

It also has a specific "stop and go" playback mode I needed, and it's mainly designed to be very easy to use (and pretty to look at, I hope !).

Comment: It's now 2022. The iOS music app still doesn't have crossfade, and Stop&Go is by far the best app for playing a playlist with crossfade. Thanks for making it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test it yet, but:

Making a playlist in iTunes
Highlighting all songs. 
Right click and choose Show info (In danish: Vis Info)
Last menu "Choice" (danish: Valg) 
Here the bottom entry point is "Albun without pause" No/Yes

I have choosen Yes and am now waiting to get home where I have my cable so I can sync with my iPhone 3GS too se if it works.

Michal

Answer (score 0):

One app which does allow crossfading (although you have to do it manually) is called Tap DJ.

Comment: Can you add a link to the app in your answer?

Answer (score -2):

The new Jam Session app I just distributed allows to do exactly that and much more:
http://www.jamsession.in
It allows to select a number of tunes from the user's library and then play them without gaps of silence between them. The next version shall also allow to handle several playlist and some one in the future also tuen the BPMs of the selected tunes - one I know how to do it...